# How to use spring mvc to receive array as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, vue.js

Convert an array object to a json string using `JSON.stringify`

```
var array = [1, 2];
let json = JSON.stringify(array);
console.log(json);
axios.get('http://localhost/goods', json).then(function (res) {
    if (res.code == 200) {
        console.log("ok");
    }
}
```

Parameters during transmission with Chrome browser console:

[image]

My goods controller class, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "goods",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteByIds(@RequestBody Integer[] ids) {
    goodsService.deleteByIds(ids);
    return "ok";
}
```

**Spring mvc can't receive an array.Or am I having a problem with writing axios code? How to solve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your request,

```
axios.get('http://localhost/goods', json)
```

It's a get request. So it won't have a body.

You can try changing the get method to post or use @RequestParameter instead of @RequestBody.

Comment: I just used @RequestParam, Cannot receive array. Because axios send an array of  `[1, 2]`

Comment: When axios sends a get request to return:Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: Please help update your change in the question. If you use RequestParameter, you can test with simple url: /test?ids[]=1&ids[]=2 or use post method with body.

Comment: `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:9090/goods?ids=1&2' ` This is no problem, your answer is good, but I am sure there is a problem with the axios code.

Comment: http://localhost:9090/goods?ids[]=1&ids[]=2 , how is the status and result?

Comment: Required Integer[] parameter 'ids' is not present.

Comment: Forgot to add `@RequestParam(value = "ids[]")` just fine.Thank you!